# Missing Attributes Inspector from XCode Utilities area

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I don't know what I did...

At the moment, I only have the File and Quick Help Inspectors in my Utilities area.  I'm missing all others, in particular the Attributes Inspector.

I've tried View > Utilties, but only see File and Quick Help... missing the others.
They were there earlier.  Not sure at what point they went missing.  I'm still getting used to the Mac keyboard and may have hit keys that caused this to happen.

Any ideas on how to get the missing inspectors back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're contextual. The extra inspectors appear depending on what you have selected. If you don't have a xib selected in the project navigator and an item selected within it, you get no attribute inspector since there's nothing with attributes to inspect...

Comment: Oh my... hand me my noob sign.  Thank you very much, I'm very new to this.  I thought I inadvertently hit buttons... saw I was missing those inspectors and not realizing that that you only see them on xib & storyboards.  I panicked... I realize my error now.  Thanks!